# How to create Gdiplus::Bitmap from CDC

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi+, gdi, msdn

I am trying to create a `Gdiplus::Bitmap` from a device context. The function I use is:

```
Bitmap bitmap((HBITMAP)myDC.GetCurrentBitmap(), (HPALETTE)myDC.GetCurrentPalette());
```

...but when I draw the bitmap on the screen, all I see is a black rectangle. I think I'm using the `Bitmap` constructor wrong, because in docs it's written:

> Do not pass to the GDI+ Bitmap::Bitmap constructor a GDI bitmap or a
>   GDI palette that is currently (or was previously) selected into a
>   device context.

But I have no idea how to go around this. Another approach I tried is using:

> To capture the preexisting image from a window, a Windows Graphics Device Interface (GDI) function such as BitBlt() or StretchBlt() would have to be used to copy the image from the screen to a memory bitmap. This memory bitmap could then be used in the overloaded Bitmap constructor, which takes an HBITMAP as a parameter.

But I couldn't achieve this either.

Comment: You've provided the documentation that tells you *exactly* what you need to do. Show us some code and tell us what didn't work about it.

Comment: `HBITMAP hBmp = GetCurrentObject(DC, OBJ_BITMAP);`  will give you an `HBITMAP`.. Use that for the constructor to the `Bitmap`. Otherwise create the `HBITMAP` manually from the DC by setting up the `BITMAPINFO` structure and calling `CreateDIBitmap`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Brandon, HBITMAP hBmp = GetCurrentObject(DC, OBJ_BITMAP); did the trick for me, I don't know why I couldn't find it through google, thanks again :)

Comment: @Mark Ransom, sry I didn't specify what I couldn't do, but I tried lots of things to get HBITMAP from a DC, but they all couldn't give me what I need, when using the Gdiplus::Bitmap constructor.